# .Net - Whats the difference between a Session Facade and Business Delegate?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, com+

What I understand so far:

Business Delegate - In the presentation tier, as an ASP component, provides an interface for ASP views to access business components without exposing their API, therefore reducing coupling between the two.

Session Facade - In the business tier, as a com+ component, encapsulates business objects, provides a course grain interface for views to access business components. Reduces coupling, hides complex business component interaction from views.

So what is the actual difference? They seem pretty similar to me..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Session Facade* resides on the **business-tier**. A facade encapsulates complex interactions between business objects participating in a workflow, provides a coarse-grained service interface to clients and **takes care of transaction boundaries**.

The Business Delegate resides on the **presentation-tier**. It is used to reduce the coupling between the presentation-tier and the business tier and **hides the clients from** all **the complexity** related to network calls (locating and calling the remote component, handling exceptions, etc).

So *Business Delegate* and *Session Facade* are related and are used together (there is usually a one-to-one mapping between a delegate and a facade) but they are different and have different motivations.

Comment: so could they be used together?

Comment: @KP65: Yes, as I wrote it explicitly.

Comment: Just to nitpick, but I think the Business Delegate is on the Business tier?

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine No, Business Delegate is on the presentation tier. It basically act as a central interface between business logic and presentation tier.